How can I make gstreamer's h264parse infer the correct framerate from an RTP stream
My approach is to store a RTP/h264 stream directly to an AVI movie using gstreamer.
But it fails at negotiating the caps between h264parse and avimux, because h264parse wants to negotiate a variable framerate=0/1. Using capssetter to enforce the framerate does work, but then I always have to assume the source framerate. I do have in fact some cameras which send an RTP/h264 stream from which gstreamer can deduct the framerate using the minimal examples below, but it does not work if I build a streaming pipeline in software.
I boiled it down to this minimal example (without any udpsink/-source):
Working example without RTP
gst-launch-1.0 \
  videotestsrc num-buffers=90 is-live=true ! \
  video/x-raw,width=1280,height=960,framerate=30/1 ! \
  videoconvert ! \
  openh264enc ! \
  video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream,alignment=au ! \
  avimux ! \
  fakesink

-v reports the following negotiated caps for avimux: /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAviMux:avimux0.GstPad:video_0: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, profile=(string)constrained-baseline, width=(int)1280, height=(int)960, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)bt709, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono
Not working example with RTP
gst-launch-1.0 \
  videotestsrc num-buffers=90 is-live=true ! \
  video/x-raw,width=1280,height=960,framerate=30/1 ! \
  videoconvert ! \
  openh264enc ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream,alignment=au ! \
  rtph264pay ! 'application/x-rtp,media=video,payload=96,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264,framerate=30/1' ! \
  rtph264depay ! \
  h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream,alignment=au,framerate=30/1 ! \
  avimux ! \
  fakesink

gstreamer reports an internal data stream error and GST_DEBUG=3 reveals: 0:00:00.084471587 229568 0x56490c160920 WARN                GST_CAPS gstpad.c:5757:pre_eventfunc_check:<capsfilter3:sink> caps video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, width=(int)1280, height=(int)960, framerate=(fraction)0/1, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)constrained-baseline, level=(string)3.2 not accepted
Enforcing caps does work again
gst-launch-1.0 \
  videotestsrc num-buffers=90 is-live=true ! \
  video/x-raw,width=1280,height=960,framerate=30/1 ! \
  videoconvert ! \
  openh264enc ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream,alignment=au ! \
  rtph264pay ! 'application/x-rtp,media=video,payload=96,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264,framerate=30/1' ! \
  rtph264depay ! \
  h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream,alignment=au ! \
  capssetter caps=video/x-h264,framerate=30/1 ! \
  avimux ! \
  fakesink

-v reports the following negotiated caps for avimux:
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAviMux:avimux0.GstPad:video_0: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, profile=(string)constrained-baseline, width=(int)1280, height=(int)960, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)bt709, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2, multiview-mode=(string)mono, multiview-flags=(GstVideoMultiviewFlagsSet)0:ffffffff:/right-view-first/left-flipped/left-flopped/right-flipped/right-flopped/half-aspect/mixed-mono

Really, don't use AVI as container. RTP has no concept of a frame rate. If at best, there is description info in SDP.

Am I the only one who would prefer a clean c/c++ api over this string of things you would have to google for hours to put together, without even knowing if the combination of stuff you need is really supported?

Why does Look the Pipeline so complex i suppose its just for Testing because. Why not just use gst-launch-1.0
rtspsrc location="rtsp://url" !
rtph264depay ! h264parse !
mp4mux ! filesink location=output.mp4 or for avi just replace mp4mux with avimux and set correct file Extension
